# Error when searching for date: Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error when running this macro: "Object variable or With block variable not set"

I am trying to find a date in Row 3 of a worksheet based on user input (Month and Year they want to make a report for). When the date is found, I need to store the 13th row value of the column that the date is in. The 13th row value would be stored as **AmountInv**.

The dates are the last day of each month, formatted MM/DD/YYYY. I'm using DateSerial() to get the last day. Since 0 returns the last day of the previous month, I altered the original user input as "**CurrentMonth** + 1". This worked in a test, and when in debug mode I can see that **MyDate** is the correct date I need. But, **aFind** says its value is "Nothing", which causes the error to appear for ColumnLetterA. I'm pretty sure it's just not finding the date in row 3 (even though it's definitely there, currently in column R). I've also tried changing the date to a serial number using CLng(). Neither work.

The date in the spreadsheet is formatted as Oct-19, and if you select the cell the formula box reads it as 10/31/2019. I've tried formatting the date both ways, as well as converting it to the numerical serial number. I can't think of anything else to try. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
        Dim aFind As Range
        Dim AmountInv As Variant
        Dim ColumnLetterA As String
        Dim MyDate
        Dim MonthEdit As Variant
        Dim DateSerialNum As Long

        MonthEdit = CurrentMonth + 1
        MyDate = DateSerial(CurrentYear, MonthEdit, 0)
        DateSerialNum = CLng(MyDate)

        With Range("A3:BB3")
        Set aFind = .Find(What:=DateSerialNum, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        End With

        ColumnLetterA = Split(Cells(1, aFind.Column).Address, "$")(1)

        AmountInv = Range(ColumnLetterA & "13")
```

Comment: You need to check if the `.Find` returned something or not. `ColumnLetterA = Split(Cells(1, aFind.Column).Address, "$")(1)` is assuming that `aFind` is "something" You need to check first `If not aFind is nothing then ColumnLetterA = Split(Cells(1, aFind.Column).Address, "$")(1): else : Msgbox "Not Found"`

Comment: [Here](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) is an example of how to use `.Find`

Comment: `the formula box reads it as 10/31/2019` Use this `.Find(What:="10/31/2019", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)`

Comment: I've had issues with find and strings - convert MyDate to a string, and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the input, turns out it was searching in the active sheet instead of the sheet I needed it to search, AND the search criteria needed to be a string. Thank you very much!